# Passing arguments to WordPress feed URL

Tags: wordpress, rss

As we all know the WordPress' feed url is www.mysite.com/feed.

I have edited the feed-rss2.php file to show thumbnails if a certain GET parameter is passed. See the code below:

```
 <?php if($_GET['c'] == 'detailswiththumb') echo the_post_thumbnail( array(100,100) );  ?>
```

But when I open the feed address like this:

www.mysite.com/feed?c=detailswiththumb

The code doesn't work. Can the arguments be passed this way? Am I missing something? Please help.

Comment: Can you post your feed loop? Or even better to debug the situation, try it with different `$_GET` values, then exit the script to make sure you're accessing it correctly.

Comment: It's not a good practice to edit core files, you should consider hooks instead.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the function is get_the_post_thumbnail() not the_post_thumbnail().

Then, their is one more problem in your code, that you have to pass the post id to get its thumbnail (for more info see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail).

So, first you will have to extract the post id from somewhere and then only you would be able to get the thumbnail. But, I think it would be very tough, so try giving up this thought, for it would take you a lot of time and no living being is going to access that path.

Answer (score 0):

There were browser cache issues. Even with Google Chrome's incognito window. Had to test it with passing fake arguments like...

www.mysite.com/feed?c=detailswiththumb&fakearguments=123

...to clear the cache. And the code is fine.

Sorry for wasting your time guys.